# How to parse Muc Sub events packet using Smack 4

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am developing a chat app. And I have a performance problem when my app gets started. I am using Muc and ejabberd on the server side. The thing is I have to join all the rooms and set A EnterConfigurations to get the Archives.
I found that Ejabberd has Muc sub but **smack** does not have that implemented to parse Incoming Event packets.
Does anyone have the implementation of mucsub using smack 4?